# SUMIF Formula for Partial Text and Partial Numbers

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

**Aim**

Currently trying to create a SUMIF formula that recognises the partial text in a range and returns the sum of the number reflecting it.

[image]

.

**Research & Results**

I have looked into SUMIF for partial text:
`=SUMIF(B2:B3,"*"&B5&"*",C2:C3)` which returns 0.

I have also looked into using `LEFT(C2:C3,1)` : `=SUMIF(B2:B3,"*"&B5&"*",LEFT(C2:C3))`

However returns N/A.

.

Any advice on this would be appreciated

[Sample Script](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-yCxXlRpTn68zKD7Ns-JKZ7Yd17Gxy_2-upe6cXplZ0/edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=index(transpose(query({split(B2,"|");split(C2:C3,"|")},"select sum(Col1),sum(Col2)")))
```